# UITableView UIImageView image Flickering - iOS/Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

For some reason when I'm downloading my image using **GCD**, the image will randomly start flickering.

I'll reset the content settings in simulator and it'll work once, then it'll just start flickering again.

This is the code I am using. I've got the reloads in there because if I don't reload it, the image doesn't show until I tap on the cell.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.entries.arrayimage];
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];


    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        cell.imageView.image = nil;
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        cell.imageView.image = img;
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    });


});
return cell;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer, more of a suggestion:  You should look into SDWebCache (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).  It accomplishes exactly what you are doing here but with a cleaner interface, and probably will not lead to the artifacts you are experiencing, which may be due to threading issues (though it's tough to say from just that small snippet of code).  Also, based on personal experience, you shouldn't judge any rendering issues based on the simulator.  You should test your app on a real device.

Comment: I had the same problem on my iOS simulator. I tried it on an actual device, it worked fine with no lag.

Comment: ah I don't have any developer programs yet so I can't test on my device.

Thanks aeskreis, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue` to async load imageData from file. Using this style load image in `cellForRow` will make cell image should should previous image first. Then finish async load, will call `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),` to load the image you want to. Therefore, whenever you reloadData or any other methods to call `cellForRow`, the cell image will flicker.

I know you want to load image without blocking main thread, but it's not a good way.

Answer (score 1):

Check out apple sample code for Lazy Image loading. And also I checked your code and found that you always downloading image from URL. Instead of that its good to download and save image in caches and then load image from next time in cellForRowAtIndexPath method from local caches if available.

Answer (score 0):

Is this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

If that is the case, the problem here is that all the cells are infinitely reloading the table. You should not be calling `reloadData` in any of datasource methods that are triggered by `reloadData`.

What you have is basically an infinite loop of reloading. (`reloadData` triggers `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` which once again triggers `reloadData`).

My suggestion is to use an external component for this as aeskreis posted in his comment.

[SDWebImage](http://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) is probably the best one out there and will allow you to simplify all of the code you have there into simply:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.entries.arrayimage];
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url];
```

Comment: yeah it is in cellForRowAtIndexPath. 

ahhh I thought it was constantly reloading, that's why I was trying to move the reloadData around but couldn't get it working. 

as I'm doing this for a uni project, I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use external component's.

Answer (score 0):

Okay Guys I found out the problem. It was constantly reloading the data which caused te flickering. instead of [self.tableView reloadData] I replaced it with this method:

```
        [cell setNeedsLayout];
```

I believe this method detects if anything has been changed, and then updates it (from my memory of a couple hours ago so it's probably not 100% accurate), but that fixed my problem.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.entries.arrayimage];
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        cell.imageView.image = img;
        //[self.tableView reloadData];
        [cell setNeedsLayout];
    });
});
return cell;
```